# Hovering Effect in a button isn't working with css modules in react

Tags: css

I have 2 different hovering Effects on a button. The one with the `.Red` class works perfectly fine but the general `.Button` class doesn't.

```css
.Button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font: inherit;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
};
//this one doesn't work
.Button:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  color: black;
}

.Button.Red {
  background-color: red;
}

.Button.Red:hover {
  background-color: salmon;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="Button">Click Me</button>

<button class="Button Red">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question as well so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I will be doing this moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

You have a ";" after "}" remove it and it should work.

```
.Button {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  font: inherit;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
};
```

Comment: OMG i can't believe that i actually missed that one! Thank you so much! It is working now :)